# How to install the avtp plugin from GStreamer in Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, alsa, plugins, gstreamer

My system environment:
A PC with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS; GStreamer version: 1.16.3

I would like to install the AVTP plugin from GStreamer.
I tried these:

1. I have used the following commands to install GStreamer and its plugins-base/good/bad/ugly, libav, ALSA etc:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc build-essential libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools \
gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
```

2. I have installed the libavtp from https://github.com/AVnu/libavtp by using the following commands:

```
meson build --prefix=/usr/local
ninja -C build
sudo ninja -C build install
```

It seems successful. No errors appear.

However, after I complete those steps, I still can't use AVTP plugins on my Ubuntu.
It says "No such element or plugin 'avtp'" after I input the command to the terminal:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 avtp
```

The webpage https://tsn.readthedocs.io/avb.html tells me that "The AVTP plugin is part of alsa-plugins since version 1.1.8.". I don't understand why I still can't use the AVTP plugin after I have installed the alsa-plugins. Is it possible that I install the libavtp in the wrong directory?

Can anyone please let me know how to install the avtp plugin correctly?
Thank you.